# Autofac Intercept Target Method

Tags: c#, aop, autofac, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm using Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 to perform some method interception on a service implementation.

The service has quite a few methods and I only want to target a few.

Is there a better practice besides than checking for invocation target name against an approved string dictionary of methods I want to intercept?

```
   public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();
        if (ContinueIntercept(invocation))
        {
            // Do intercept work
        }
    }

    private bool ContinueIntercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {            
        // Logic to compare invocation.MethodInvocationTarget.Name 
    }
```

It really doesn't add all that much over head, but it still feels like a poor way to do it.  Especially since adding this to a specific service implementation means it will intercept all of the method calls of the base class common implementation.  It wouldn't be as bad if it only intercepted the derived class.

I see that Castle.DynamicProxy2 has ways to specify invocation target, but I don't see how to wire that up with autofac.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the [docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html) say "Class interception requires the methods being intercepted to be virtual since it uses subclassing as the proxy technique.", so you could try removing the virtual modifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `IProxyGenerationHook` to specify on which method the `ProxyBuilder` should generate a proxy.

```cs
public class FooProxyGenerationHook : IProxyGenerationHook
{
    public void MethodsInspected()
    { }

    public void NonProxyableMemberNotification(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo)
    { }

    public Boolean ShouldInterceptMethod(Type type, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (type == typeof(Foo) && methodInfo.Name == "Do")
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, you can register it this way :

```cs
    ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
    FooProxyGenerationHook hook = new FooProxyGenerationHook();
    IFoo foo = generator.CreateClassProxyWithTarget<Foo>(new Foo(), new ProxyGenerationOptions(hook), new FooInterceptor());
```

In order to avoid calling the `IProxyGenerationHook` for each proxy, you should have only one instance of `hook`.

With DynamicProxy2, you can use this code :

```cs
    FooProxyGenerationHook hook = new FooProxyGenerationHook();

    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<FooInterceptor>().AsSelf();
    builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>()
            .EnableClassInterceptors(new ProxyGenerationOptions(hook))
            .InterceptedBy(typeof(FooInterceptor));
```

Comment: +1 from me. It's worthwhile pointing out that "[for performance reasons] always override Equals/GetHashCode methods on all your classes implementing IProxyGenerationHook" https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy-generation-hook-override-equals-gethashcode.md

Comment: However with this approach, you still have to maintain a list of methods to be intercepted in this ShouldInterceptMethod() method. Is there a way to use attribute in *method* level *with parameters* like [Logging(OutputLevel="Verbose")]?

Comment: @Calvin : in the shouldintercept method you can access attributes of the method by using the GetCustomAttributes method